# Alternativoj por baldegaŭ kaj baldetaŭ

Tags: affixes

Mi sufiĉe ofte aŭdas la vortojn *baldetaŭ* kaj *baldegaŭ* en la neformala lingvo. Ili kompreneble estas kreitaj el la vorto *baldaŭ*. Estas multe da vortoj kiuj finiĝas per *-aŭ* kaj tio kreas la impreson ke ĝi estas ia adverba finaĵo. Tial oni sentas ke logike oni povus aldoni sufiksojn antaŭ tiu finaĵo.

Do la signifoj estas:

**baldetaŭ** – En la proksima estonteco, sed verŝajne mi faros aliajn aferojn unue, eble post kelkaj horoj.

**baldegaŭ** – Mi faros tion kiel eble plej baldaŭ, antaŭ la aliaj taskoj.

Ĉu tiuj vortoj estas akcepteblaj? Se ne, kiujn alternativajn formon oni povas uzi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gramatike ne sed oni uzas ĉar `baldaŭ` estas iel aparta inter la aliaj `-aŭ` vortoj. `Hodiaŭ`, aŭ `hieraŭ` estas tre klaraj, ne subjektivaj (se vi diras `morgaŭ` je noktomezo kaj duono, oni tamen komprenas ke ne temas pri la tago post la fakta hodiaŭ, sed pri la perceptata hodiaŭ).

`Baldaŭ` tamen, estas subjektiva, grada, kaj tial oni sentas sin rajtigita uzi ĝin kiel radikon, same kiel oni faras kun `tre` (*treege*) aŭ `tro` (*troigi*).

Ĉu ĝustas diri `baldaŭete`? Jes, ĉar oni jam uzas `baldaŭa` prefikse, ekde la infaneco de la lingvo.

```
 nin ŝovos antaŭen al la baldaŭa realigo de esperantismo.
```

(Zamenhof)

Ĉu ĝustas diri `baldetaŭ`?

Gramatike ne, sed oni devas kompreni ke por kelkaj esperantoparolantoj la `-aŭ` finaĵo estas adverba finaĵo (kvankam ĝi estas tuta vorto). En vivanta lingvo tiaj esceptoj estas normalaj kaj mi certas ke por denaskuloj, la procezo estas: apartigi la ŝajnfinaĵon, kunmeti, kaj remeti ĝin.

Fakte mi ĵus demandis al denaskulo kaj baldetaŭ estis tute komprenebla, malfacilis klarigi kiam oni demandus pri ĝia ĝusteco.

Ankaŭ grada estas `apenaŭ`, kaj mi jam aŭdis, kaj komprenas, `apenetaŭ`.

Do `baldetaŭ` kaj `baldegaŭ` ne estas gramatike ĝustaj, oni evitu ilin, sed ili plu aperos, ĉefe en naturaj ĉiutagaj esperantaj medioj.

Alternativoj?

Aldoni `tre`: `tre baldaŭ`.

Answer (score 3):

Adverboj estas el du tipoj: primitivaj kaj tiuj kun la finaĵo *e*. Ne ekzistas aliaj. Pravas, ke ekzistas kelkaj adverboj, kiuj finiĝas per la literoj *aŭ*, sed malgraŭ ĉi tio la kombinaĵo *aŭ* ne estas adverba finaĵo en Esperanto. Alivorte *baldaŭ* estas kompleta vorto (primitiva adverbo), ne kombinaĵo de iu radiko, *bald/*, plus finaĵo *aŭ*. Ĉi tial oni ne povas meti finaĵon *et* aŭ *eg* enen de la radiko.

Comment: Mi konsentas kun ĉi tiu respondo. Kelkfoje mi ja aŭdas _baldaŭege_. Mi supozas, ke tiu formo ja eblas... sed ĝi ne estas ofta. Mi trovas neniun trafon en Tekstaro, ekzemple.

Answer (score 3):

## Ĉu tiuj vortoj estas akcepteblaj?

Gramatike, **ne**.

*baldaŭ* estas el vortklazo, kiun [lernu.net nomigas](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/adverboj#adverbecaj-vortetoj) **adverbecaj vortetoj**:

> Iuj el la vortetoj en Esperanto povas roli adverbece en frazo, sed ili ne havas E-finaĵon. Tiaj estas [la tabelvortoj je E, EL, OM, AM kaj AL](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/tabelvortoj), [la vortetoj *pli* kaj *plej*](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/komparado), [la vorteto *ne*](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/negacio), la vortetoj *ĉi*, *for*, *ankoraŭ*, ***baldaŭ***, *hodiaŭ*, *hieraŭ*, *morgaŭ*, *jam*, *ĵus*, *nun*, *plu*, *tuj*, *ajn*, *almenaŭ*, *ankaŭ*, *apenaŭ*, *des*, *do*, *eĉ*, *ja*, *jen*, *jes*, *ju*, *kvazaŭ*, *mem*, *nur*, *preskaŭ*, *tamen*, *tre* kaj *tro*. Adverbecaj vortetoj principe estas adverboj, sed en tiu ĉi gramatiko ili estas nomataj **adverbecaj vortetoj** por klare distingi ilin de tiuj adverboj, kiuj havas E-finaĵon.

Adverbeca vorteto kompreneble estas vorteto. [lernu.net definas *vorteto* tiel](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/terminoj#vl-vorteto):

> **vorteto**
>
> Vorto, kiu ne bezonas finaĵon, sed kiu povas aperi en frazo tia, kia ĝi estas.

Ĝies sekcio pri vortospecoj en la ĉapitro [Vortospecoj kaj frazroloj](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/vortospecoj) kontrastas *vortetoj* kun "*finaĵvortoj*" kaj [pri la lastaj skribas](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/vortospecoj#finajhvortoj):

> Finaĵvorto baze konsistas el **radiko** (aŭ pluraj radikoj) + vortklasa finaĵo [...].

Do vortetoj ne estas finajvortoj, kaj verŝajne implice sekvas ke ili **ne** konsistas el radiko(j) + vortklasa finaĵo.

PMEG 15.0.13 enhavas [similan definon de "vorteto"](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/superrigardo/vortospecoj.html#i-m3h) kaj [similan kontrastadon](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/superrigardo/vortospecoj.html) inter "*radikvortoj*" (=finajvortoj) kaj *vortetoj*:

> Ekzistas du specoj de vortoj en Esperanto: **radikvortoj** kaj **vortetoj**.

Plie, ĝi skribas, ke

> [k]vankam vortetoj ne bezonas finaĵojn por roli vorte, oni povas aldoni finaĵojn kaj afiksojn por krei novajn vortojn kun aliaj signifoj [...]

Do en la vortfarsistemo de Esperanto eblas uzi *tuta*(!) vorteto *kiel* radiko, sed **ne** eblas trakti ilin kiel radikvortoj / finajvortoj kun finaĵo.

(PMEG mencias escepto por poezio:)

> **Noto:** Okazis provoj ŝanĝi iujn E-vortecajn vortetojn, kiuj finiĝas per “aŭ”, en radikvortojn, ekz.: *hodiaŭ* → **hodie**, *ankoraŭ* → **ankore**, *almenaŭ* → **almene**. Nur en poezio oni povus ankoraŭ renkonti tiajn formojn. En ordinara lingvaĵo oni nepre restu ĉe la normalaj formoj.

## Se ne, kiujn alternativajn formon oni povas uzi?

Laŭ tiuj reguloj ***baldaŭete*** kaj ***baldaŭege*** eblus, sed mi nek komprenis ilin, nek (sen via eksplikado) **baldetaŭ** aŭ **baldegaŭ**. (Kaj eĉ kun la eksplikado, mi ankoraŭ ne certas ĉu **baldetaŭ** estus pli frua au malpli frua ol *baldaŭ*.

Por *mi faros tion kiel eble plej baldaŭ, antaŭ la aliaj taskoj* eblas simple uzi:

> tuj

Eble oni simple uzu multaj vortoj por *en la proksima estonteco, sed verŝajne mi faros aliajn aferojn unue, eble post kelkaj horoj*:

> baldaŭ, sed ne tuj